# Keep file as deleted in git merge (script)

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

We are doing a git merge where we have deleted a lot of files in the destination branch which have also changed in the source branch.  I gather this can be resolved by `git rm <file>`.  How can you run this command via script for all files which have this type of conflict?